# Regex equivalent to find all mp3 and mp4 files but not .avi in windows10

Tags: regex, windows, search, windows-10

I have used some naming conventions for mp3 files in windows os and I want to find all songs containing "xyz" but not "abc". Any regex equivalent method to do it in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched this a bit, and apparently `findstr`, while having the ability to do regex search on Windows, does not support lookarounds.  This is important because the `not "abc"` requirement would best be served using a lookaround.  Here is a regex which would match filenames which you want.

I am here offering a Linux based solution, which can be made to run on Windows.  Here is a regex which would match the filenames you want:

```
^(?!.*abc).*xyz.*\.mp(?:3|4)$
```

## Demo

In Linux, you could try the following `find`:

```
find | grep -P '(?!.*abc).*xyz.*\.mp(?:3|4)'
```

There are a number of tools out there which can simulate Linux on Windows, such as Cygwin.  I believe the Git bash also supports some Linux commands.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for method to search in file explorer itself.. else I was looking for an app in windows store as add-on to file-explorer.. else may be I can build new app with good GUI to build a regex and use it to search files. I just searched "regex" and "filtering file" in app store. No use.

Comment: @Shivakumar There is a bigger problem in that you not only need regex, you probably need PCRE regex which even Windows' `findstr` does not support.  So if I were you, I would just do this search from a tool like Cygwin.

Comment: can we also start vlc player using Cygwin, adding all filtered files to vlc player? I am not sure if Cygwin will support select->drag->drop GUI functionality

Comment: Probably not.  Now I see your requirements are larger than what it seemed initially.  You could write a small .NET code to handle this fairly easily (or maybe Java).